# encodeURIComponent() ignoring newline chars

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to save textarea value to .txt file.

the code works fine but when I download the file, the newline chars are not preserved and all the content is printed on one single line.

code:

```js
var fname;
var fnote;

function download() {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  fname = document.getElementById("title").value;
  fnote = document.getElementById("note").value;
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(fnote));
  element.setAttribute('download', fname);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);
  element.click();
  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Javascript - Create Text file</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div>
      <p>title:</p>
      <input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title.." style="border: solid 1px #957dad;">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <p>note:</p>
      <textarea name="note" rows="15" cols="70" id="note" placeholder="Enter your text here.." style="padding: 2%; border-color: #957dad; border-width: 3px; resize: none; max-width: 100%;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Download" onclick="download()" class="btn btn-primary">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I ran your code here and I got newlines.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar. Working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/em3hpztw/

Comment: Though note that you'd be better using a Blob and a blob:URI rather than a data: URI. `element.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([fnote]));`